# newCard.fireEvent is not a function for ExtJS 5.1.1

Tags: model-view-controller, extjs, controller, navigateurl

I have a Viewport and it has two content: Menu and Main Content. During click event for Menu items, I get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: newCard.fireEvent is not a function`

What am I missing for `navigate` function? Here are `View` and `Controller`;

MainView:

```
Ext.define('CalTable.view.MainView', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',
    alias: 'widget.mainview',

    requires: [
        'Ext.menu.Menu',
        'Ext.menu.Item',
        'Ext.form.Label'
    ],

    itemId: 'mainView',
    layout: 'border',
    defaultListenerScope: true,

    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            region: 'west',
            split: true,
            itemId: 'menuPanel',
            width: 150,
            title: 'Menu',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'menu',
                    floating: false,
                    itemId: 'menu',
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'menuitem',
                            itemId: 'home',
                            text: 'Home',
                            focusable: true
                        }, {
                            xtype: 'menuitem',
                            itemId: 'folioList',
                            text: 'Folio List',
                            focusable: true
                        }, {
                            xtype: 'menuitem',
                            itemId: 'calendar',
                            text: 'Calendar',
                            focusable: true
                        }
                    ],
                    listeners: {click: 'onMenuClick'}
                }
            ]
        }, {
            xtype: 'panel',
            region: 'center',
            itemId: 'contentPanel',
            layout: 'card',
            scope: this,
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    itemId: 'homePanel',
                    title: 'Home',
                    layout: {
                        type: 'vbox',
                        align: 'center',
                        pack: 'center'
                    },
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'label',
                            text: 'Home View'
                        }
                    ]
                }, {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    itemId: 'folioPanel',
                    title: 'Folio List',
                    layout: {
                        type: 'vbox',
                        align: 'center',
                        pack: 'center'
                    },
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'label',
                            text: 'Folio List View'
                        }
                    ]
                }, {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    itemID: 'calendarPanel',
                    title: 'Calendar',
                    layout: {
                        type: 'vbox',
                        align: 'center',
                        pack: 'center'
                    }, 
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'label',
                            text: 'Calendar View'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],

    onMenuClick: function(menu, item, e, eOpts) {
        location.hash = item.itemId;
    }
});
```

and of course Controller:

```
Ext.define('CalTable.controller.TheController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    requires: ['Ext.util.History'],

    refs: {
        contentPanel: '#contentPanel',
        menu: '#menu',
        menuPanel: '#menuPanel'
    },

    onLaunch: function () {
        Ext.History.init();
        Ext.History.on('change', this.navigate, this);
        this.navigate(window.location.hash);
    },

    navigate: function (id) {
        if (id) {
            if (id[0] == '#') id = id.slice(1);
            this.getContentPanel().layout.setActiveItem(id + 'Panel');
            this.getMenu().items.each(function (item) {
                if (item.href == '#' + id) {
                    item.disable();
                    window.document.title = item.text;
                }
                else {
                    item.enable();
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is caused in this line:

```
this.getContentPanel().layout.setActiveItem(id + 'Panel');
```

because the underlying issue is that the ids of the menu items and the cards have to match.

You have the menu items

```
home
folioList
calendar
```

but the ids you have in your card layout are

```
homePanel
folioPanel
calendarPanel
```

So when the menu item with id `folioList` is clicked and subsequently `setActiveItem("folioListPanel")` is executed, but no item with id `folioListPanel` exists, that obscure error is thrown in ExtJS.

While changing the id should fix the problem at hand, what you definitely also want to do is to amend the controller to check whether the item really exists before navigating, because navigation can also be executed through a user-changed anchor, and you don't want your user to break your app that way.